# What is an efficient algorithm to move a particle by a specific distance in a chosen direction along the surface of a polygon mesh?

Tags: polygon, physics, mesh

I have a polygon mesh that defines a 3d object (let's assume the 3d object is a dolphin). I have a point on the 3d mesh that I want to move in a specified direction along the surface of the mesh by distance 'd'. What algorithm or method do I use to do this?

One possible way I can think of doing this is by:

1. Define a directional vector for the particle's movement along the face it is sitting on (if the particle is sitting on an edge or vertex, the directional vector can be defined along an adjacent face or edge).
2. Move the particle in that direction till it encounters a vertex or edge.
3. Alter the particle's movement vector to keep it constrained to the surface of the mesh while continuing to move 'forward' (not sure how to implement this part).

Keep doing this till the particle has traveled a net distance of 'd'.

Comment: Sounds like a good method, although for it to be efficient you would need a way to query adjacent triangles – half-edge might be useful. Also the new direction might not be well-defined if two faces are at right angles to each other.